# How to use sshpass to sftp upload file?

Tags: ftp, sftp, scp, upload, sshpass

I have following :

```
$ cat upload.sh
sshpass -f ~/path_to_password/pass.txt sftp user@remote.location.net:/pools/path/ << EOF
put backup.tar
EOF
```

When i execute the `upload.sh` it shows nothing (file is not uploaded) and does not exit auto. How to properly exit and make sure the upload is made?

Comment: take a look at [sexpect](https://github.com/clarkwang/sexpect) which you can use to write Expect like scripts with shell only.